# New Asus laptop freezes every couple of minutes when on battery

Tags: asus, freeze, touchscreen

This problem is different than :
[New asus with ubuntu keeps freezing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353275/new-asus-with-ubuntu-keeps-freezing)
and
[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Actually i have 3 major problems I'll list according to importance :
Couple of information first :
I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64bits on newly purchased Asus SonicMaster s551l with touchscreen , it comes with dual video cards Intel's and nvidia gforce gt 740m (I'm using proprietary drivers).

Problems :
1- when on battery mode (no charger pluged in) ubuntu keeps freezing every 3 minutes (average) meaning nothing works except sound (mouse doesn't move or click, screen stays still i.e when playing video stays on the same frame), example when i play video on youtube then it freezes the sound keeps playing , until now my solution was to close the laptop led wait a couple of seconds then login and every works as nothing happened .
this is ubuntu only problem cause it doesn't happen in windows i tested before i asked here .

2- Touch screen related issues : i have unity laucher on auto hide but it doesn't show up when i swipe from the sides , plus chrome tabs can't be selected dragged closed (by touching x) or even create new tab by touching the "+" button.

3- Function + bright buttons don't work (only these two) , I can't play with screen brightness using the keyboard (i can still through the setting though) .

Answer (score 0):

the first problem caused by nvidia driver

if u dont have important files reinstall ubuntu then install nvidia proprietery driver ( NOT THE ONE TESTED , only PROPRIETERY ) then search in the dash for nvidia setting and set the graphic card as intel , the nvidia this time will not hang but it flikr a little thats why i told u to set intel as graph card

u cant set brightness using keyboard shortcuts in ubuntu as far as i know so dont bother

i have the same notebook except a non touch screen

if ur a normal user intel will be fine for every thing in ubuntu

Comment: thanks for the reply but i'm using nvidia for playing games i have a lot in steam , what about them ? , plus reinstalling  ubuntu kindda an extreme solution which i can't afford right now :/

Comment: go to additional driver and select the proprietery driver (not the tested one ) u will see two , one proprietary and other proprietary,tested , select the propritary and apply changes , wait till it finish , restart pc , in dash search for nvidia setting , open it and scroll down and select nvidia as graph card

Answer (score 0):

1- You can also switch drivers without reinstalling:

- Open the "Additional Drivers" utility
- Select the driver you wish to use
- Type your password
- Wait for it install
- Reboot

2 - Unfortunately I don't own a touchscreen and have now idea how to fix this. Maybe wait for Ubuntu 14.10? I heard it's supposed to be a lot better optimized for touch screens...

3 - For backlight support try installing this:
https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/blob/master/install/deb/nvidiabl-dkms_0.87_all.deb
Then run this using `Alt`+`F2` und enter you password:
`pkexec sh -c "echo nvidiabl > /etc/modules-load.d/nvidiabl.conf"`
and reboot.

Comment: well changing the driver seems to have fixed the freezing problem , somehow i had the proprietary and testing driver installed , but for the brightness the .deb didn't help .