# Asus Laptop on Ubuntu 16.04 freezes while on battery

Tags: 16.04, drivers, power-management, battery, freeze

I bought a new Asus R510V laptop and after installing Ubuntu 16.04, I found out that whenever I pull the power cable out of the laptop, if I wait 4-5 minutes it freezes completely. I'm going to tell you about my machine and about what I've already tried.

- The laptop has an **Intel i7-6700HQ** 3.5ghz, nvidia **Geforce 950m**, 8gb
  ram, 256gb ssd.
- I use **nvidia-375.39** proprietary drivers that they recommended on
  their website. I've also tried with 378 (which they list as beta) and
  it didn't work. 378 was open source though.
- I'm using kernel version **4.8.0**
- This problem happens both on wired connection and wireless.
- Someone said that my disk may be corrupted. I booted from grub into safemode and typed `sudo fsck -f /`. It didn't throw any errors, only "Passed 1, Passed 2...". So I guess that is not the problem
- When the laptop freezes, `alt+sysrq+REISUB` doesn't work. Even after enabling sysrq commands explicitly. The commands do work when the laptop behaves normally, they just don't seem to do anything when it freezes.
- Some people said to turn off power management with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`. They are always `wlp2s0` instead of `wlan0`, but even so, `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off` doesn't work. Nevertheless, for me, `iwconfig` shows `Power Management:off` both for wired and wireless connections
- I created the file `/etc/pm/config.d/blacklist` and placed `HOOK_BLACKLIST="wireless"` in it. It doesn't have any effect both on wireless and wired.
- If I close the lid after freeze, it does not suspend.
- After it freezes, it waits ~10 seconds and then the fan/cooler (I think) starts blowing loudly on the left side.
- Sometimes, when I try to boot into safemode, I can see that there are some serious visual bugs. I can still type normally, but the screen messes up when I move the selection to choose "root" and debug my system in safe mode. Again, only sometimes. That is why I think it's related to the graphics driver.
- I've heard that some older Linux kernels had bugs with HQ6700, maybe it's related to this? If yes, which version do I need?

Although my laptop is not a Zenbook, I followed the instructions here (first thing after table of contents): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook

I added those extra parameters to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, I installed tlp and tweaked those options to the values they recommended, I shut the device down, removed the battery (mine is detachable), waited for a couple of minutes, booted into ubuntu and the problem persisted.

**Currently**, this is what I have in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi='Windows 2009' acpi_os_name='Windows 2009' intel_idle.max_cstate=1 acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_pstate=disable pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi='Windows 2009' acpi_os_name='Windows 2009' intel_idle.max_cstate=1 acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

In the **past**, I've also tried with this but it didn't work either:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

Yes, I did run `update-grub`.

This is what I added to `/etc/default/tlp` after installing `tlp`:

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=ondemand
CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on
```

I've also found these, which did not solve my issue:

[Ubuntu (15.10, 16.04, 16.10) freezes on resume from suspend (only on battery)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842389/ubuntu-15-10-16-04-16-10-freezes-on-resume-from-suspend-only-on-battery)

[New Asus laptop freezes every couple of minutes when on battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529624/new-asus-laptop-freezes-every-couple-of-minutes-when-on-battery)

Thank you.

Comment: Try with: https://askubuntu.com/a/315775/24155